# Printing all words that start with "@" using sed in BASH

Tags: sed, grep, match

I have a file with a lot of text, but I want to print only words that contain "@" at the beginning. Ex:

```
My name is @Laura and I live in @London. Name=@Laura. City=@London
```

How can I print all words that start with @?.I did this the following and it worked, but I want to do it using sed. I tried several patters, but I cannot make it print anything.

```
grep -o -E "@\w+" file.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this with sed? It isn't really the right tool for this job.

Comment: How do you define a "word"? Do words only contain letters? numbers? underscores? Hyphens? For example `Spencer-Churchill` is a name so it seems like it should fit in with what you are trying to extract but it contains a non-POSIX-word-constitutent character (the hyphen) so is it a word to you? What about towns that have 2 words in their name (e.g. `Sutton Benger`) - how would that appear instead of London in your example or could it not?

Comment: I want to use sed in case I need to substitute those words in the future. I cannot do that with grep. I meant "word" as in nothing but [a-z][A-Z]  and _ as I showed in my grep example using \w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command:

```
sed 's/[^@]*\(@[^ .]*\)/\1\n/g' file.txt
```

Explanation: we invoke the substitution command of `sed`. This has following structure: `sed 's/regex/replace/options'`. We will search for a regex and replace it using the `g` option. `g` makes sure the match is made multiple times per line.

We look for a series of non at chars followed by an `@` and a number of non-spaces `@[^ ]*`. We put this last part in a group `\(\)` and sub it during the replacement `\1`.

Note that we add a newline at the end of each match, you can also get the output on a single line by omitting the `\n`.

Comment: Interesting. No wonder my sed regexp wasn't working. I was trying sed -n -e 's/.*\(@\w+\) .*/\1/p'.    Thanks